# How to understand "throw" in "throw support behind"

Tags: meaning

I came across this phrase a lot in news.

> Candidates **Throw Support Behind** Catering Workers in Dispute With
>   American Airlines
>
> From
>   https://www.dmagazine.com/frontburner/2019/03/candidates-throw-support-behind-catering-workers-in-dispute-with-american-airlines/
>
> U.S. airlines **throw support behind** Bombardier in Boeing trade
>   dispute
>
> From 
>   https://business.financialpost.com/transportation/u-s-airlines-throw-support-behind-bombardier-in-boeing-trade-dispute
>
> He tweeted that the United States would **throw its support behind**
>   those protesting in Iran at an “appropriate time.”
>
> From 
>   https://aawsat.com/english/home/article/1132031/trump-us-throw-support-behind-iranian-protesters-appropriate-time

I am confused what “throw” means in this phrase. Does “throw” simply means put/place something? Or does it imply a force and a suddenness? In other words, does “throw support behind” simply mean support? Or does it mean support **forcefully/suddenly**? Since I cannot find this expression in dictionaries, I really need your help explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context I would infer **vigour** rather than **suddeness**. Imagine someone wholeheartedly helping to push a vehicle out of a ditch, throwing all their weight behind the the effort.